# "Re"-download 10.8 After Purchase of a New Mac

Tags: macos

I recently purchased a new Macbook Air which obviously came with Mountain Lion. I am wondering if there is a way to download the installer for free onto another computer I have to create a re-install disk from, without having to pay the $20 to download from the Mac App Store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download [Apple's official OSX Recovery Disk assistant](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1433) to create a flash drive with the capability to re-install OSX on an eligible Apple computer. A flash drive (it must be larger then 1GB) also enables you to easily re-install OSX on products such as the MacBook Air which don't have optical drives.

There is also a [support document about the Recovery Disk Assistant](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4848).

Comment: But if you try to use this flash drive to install OSX on another computer, won't it check on-line and see that the compluter is not eligible?

Comment: @Gedgar, yes. It probably will. However, the OP mentioned he desired a "re-install" disk - which would indicate that the computer already had ML. It also seems that one should purchase one license per computer. So if the computer didn't already have a valid OS license, then it would be necessary to purchase a download.